# Shouldn't we ensure |z|<1 before proceeding further in this question?

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

Consider, for example, the answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3182973/476145). Here, while converting the series from the denominator using the expansion of $\dfrac 1{1-y}$, why is it not ensured that $|y|< 1$. Here by $y$ I am referring to $(\dfrac{-z^{12}}{12}+\dfrac{z^4}{360}- ...)$. I have seen such conversions from denominator to a series using $1/(1-y)$ often and always seen people not ensuring that $|y|< 1$. Am I missing out something obvious?

Comment: Isn't it quite clear that $|y| <1$ is satisfied when $|z|$ is small enough?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Perhaps, but is there a way to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to choose $z$ so that $2|z|^{2} (\frac 1 {4!}+\frac 1 {6!}+\frac 1 {8!}+...) <1$ which is possible since the series $\frac 1 {4!}+\frac 1 {6!}+\frac 1 {8!}+...$ is convergent.

In the second link you only need convergence of $\sum \frac {4^{n}} {(2n)!}$

Comment: Did you see the second link? It is trickier..

Comment: @Archer That is also fairly simple, I have edited my answer.

Comment: So everytime we must show convergence like this for completeness?

Comment: @Archer Yes, this type of argument is usually considered as straightforward, so details are often omitted. But OP's can always ask for details (and you had a right to rise this question!).

Comment: Why did you use $|z|^2$ in the first condition? The series included all even powers right?

Comment: @Archer Yes, that is right.

Comment: So you assumed that |z|< 1 so $|z|^2$ is the maximum value in the series, then you applied triangle inequality to get the first condition? Is that right?

Comment: @ Exactly. That is the argument.

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks again.

Comment: I just checked, and the sum is 0.7.... so it gives $|z|^2 <  1.4$ and not $|z|^2 < 1$

Comment: @Archer: You've extended the set of usable $z$, but $|z|\lt1$ still works.